# Logo being filled with water CSS Preloader

Tags: html, css, animation, preloader

I want to create a preloader from a logo which should appear as if logo is being filled with a liquid. I want to use pure CSS.

While googling I found [Filling a glass with Water](http://priteshgupta.com/2011/07/filling-a-glass-with-water-using-html5/). But the problem with it is that it only fills in rectangle form. The logo is black/white. I have it in all formats PNG, JPEG, SVG. Here is the pictorial representation in sprites:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeF9r.png

Also it must have transparent background like PNG.

Comment: To use your example as a starting point, you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/FnPG5/1/

Answer (score 2):

Create a 'inverse cut out' of your logo and layer that on the top of the rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

Without a clear understanding of what you're exactly wanting to achieve, this would be the easiest way to go about what you want based on an assumption:

1. Save a PNG of your logo with the correct background-color and the
   letters of the logo cut-out (transparent).
2. Create a container in your HTML page that has the simple 'filling' animation.
3. Sit the PNG on top of the 'filling' container using absolute positioning.

Result: A 'filling' logo.